# CAML query error when creating SPQuery query

Tags: caml-query

I have this CAML query

```
var query = new SPQuery{
     Query = string.Format(@"<Where>
          <Or>
                <Or>
                     <Or>
                          <Or>
                                <Contains>
                                     <FieldRef Name='{7}' />
                                     <Value Type='Text'>{3}</Value>
                                </Contains>
                          </Or>
                          <Contains>
                                <FieldRef Name='{6}' />
                                <Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value>
                          </Contains>
                     </Or
                     <Contains>
                          <FieldRef Name='{5}' />
                          <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
                     </Contains>
                </Or>
                <Contains>
                     <FieldRef Name='{4}' />
                     <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                </Contains>
          </Or>
     </Where>", "title", "adress", "zipcode", "city", "searchTitle", "searchAdress", "searchZipcode", "searchCity")
};
```

Every time it's ran and I try to use `List.GetItems(query);` it throws this error:

```
One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
```

BUT! If I remove all the `<Or>` tags it works and doesn't throw that error, but I need the `<Or>` tags to make sure it get all hits.

I've made sure all the fieldrefs matches the internal names of the columns 100%.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: you mis-typed the word "address" when you created the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified incorrect column name. Try to use [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx). It will build the query based on the internal column names. Is also works with SP2010 even it doesn't specified exactly.

Answer (score 7):

Typically this error means that one of the columns you are querying is incorrect. Remember, you must use the **Internal** column name ([an easy way to find the internal column name](http://www.davehunter.co.uk/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=119)).

In this specific case, as @JamesLove points out, you have two columns that are misspelled: `adress` and `searchAdress` (also, `title` does not have the correct case).

In addition, you had an extra pair of `<Or></Or>` nodes.

```
var query = new SPQuery{
   Query = string.Format(@"<Where>
      <Or>
         <Or>
            <Or>
               <Contains>
                  <FieldRef Name='{7}' />
                  <Value Type='Text'>{3}</Value>
               </Contains>
               <Contains>
                     <FieldRef Name='{6}' />
                     <Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value>
               </Contains>
            </Or
            <Contains>
               <FieldRef Name='{5}' />
               <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
            </Contains>
         </Or>
         <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='{4}' />
            <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
         </Contains>
      </Or>
   </Where>", 
   "Title", "address", "zipcode", "city", "searchTitle", "searchAddress", "searchZipcode", "searchCity")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this can also happen when your query is actually not syntactically correct.
Extra OR, AND also result into the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw a complete alternative into the mix: This error also crops up if you have a column based on a broken or uninstalled Custom Field Type.

A quick look at the List Settings page will show you if this is the case; the troublesome columns will be marked as invalid (with the option to delete them).